# C++11 thread crash when access boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Tags: multithreading, boost, c++11, boost-asio

I found that accessing `tcp::socket` from a std::thread will cause program terminated.
Here's the sample program from boost.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp
Compile it: `g++ blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp -std=c++11 -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread`

So far, everthing works fine.
But if you replace the boost::thread with std::thread (and #include ), the program will crash(terminated) when it access sock member ( `socket::read_some()` ).

**Error message: terminate called without an active exception.**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the difference between `boost::thread` and `std::thread`. I have seen the code, and you can fix it to work with `std::thread`, just like this:

```
void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port) {
    // ...
    std::thread t(boost::bind(session, sock));
    t.detach();
}
```

It seems you must detach or join the thread when you use `std::thread`.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(void) {
    std::thread t([](){std::cout << "will throw exception" << std::endl;});
//  t.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

It will throw exception if **not detach** or **not join** or **not link pthread**

Comment: It works. Thanks.
Looks like I shouldn't find out the difference between C++ 11 libraries and Boost libraries to avoid similar issue.

Comment: @avhacker Note that this behavior of `Boost.Thread` is now deprecated: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor